# Removing inherited css in table

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble removing the inherited styles in a sub-table. My tables basically look like this:

```
<table class="twocoltable">
<thead>
    <tr><th>BlahBlah</th></tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>
        <table class="nostyle">
            <tr>
                <td>stuff</td>
                <td>stuff</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT** My .css now looks like this. The sub-table has no styles, but the parent table's td styles aren't working, but the th styles are working.

```
.twocoltable { border-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 1px solid #666666; }
.twocoltable>thead>tr>th { text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: black; font-size: 12pt; padding: 4px; background-color: #DDD; }
.twocoltable>tr>td:first-child { text-align: right; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold; color: black; font-size: 9pt; padding: 4px; border-top: 1px solid #BBBBBB; border-right: 1px solid #BBBBBB; }
.twocoltable>tr>td:last-child { text-align: left; vertical-align: top; font-weight: normal; color: #333333; font-size: 9pt; padding: 4px; border-top: 1px solid #BBBBBB; white-space: nowrap; }

.nostyle * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

What I end up with at the end is a properly formatted parent table, but the sub-table also contains the formatting. It still has the bolding, borders, and alignment.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should look into using the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having more specificity with your CSS, a great summary is [found linked here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/), it will take precedence. Maybe using an ID for your main table, and a class for your nostyle cells would be the best way to organize it?

```
<table id="twocoltable">
<table class="nostyle">
```

Another option, you can override with CSS using !important, a jsFiddle [linked here](https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/c48hq7zf/).

Comment: A couple years late, but the !important override worked out for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assign your styles only to your parent table's immediate children. This should work for properties like `margin` and `padding`. I.e.:

Instead of:

```
.twocoltable th
.twocoltable tr td:first-child
.twocoltable tr td:last-child
```

Do:

```
.twocoltable>thead>tr>th
.twocoltable>tr>td:first-child
.twocoltable>tr>td:last-child
```

However, other properties such as `font-weight` will still apply to child elements, because they are inherited. For those, you'll have to manually override in `.nostyle` definitions (which you haven't done). E.g.:

```
.nostyle {
    font-weight: normal; // initial also works
}
```

**EDIT**:

Updating my answer with a general overview of what should be the final solution.

```
.twocoltable th {
    // styles that will be applied to all th elements that live inside .twocoltable, including sub tables
}

.twocoltable tr td:first-child {
   // styles that will be applied to all elements that are the first td of a parent and live inside .twocoltable, including sub tables
}

.twocoltable tr td:last-child {
   // styles that will be applied to all elements that are the last td of a parent and live inside .twocoltable, including sub tables
}

.twocoltable>thead>tr>th {
    // styles that will be applied ONLY to th elements that are direct children of tr elements that are direct children of thead elements that are direct children of .twocoltable. This excludes sub table th elements
}

// You should have got the idea by now
.twocoltable>tr>td:first-child {...}
.twocoltable>tr>td:last-child {...}

.nostyle {
    // Styles that override styles that are inherited from its parent element even when that style has not been directly applied to it (e.g. font-weight)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above code, and it worked for the sub-table, which now has no styles... But now only the parent table and and parent header have styles, the table cells of the parent have no styles. So, it seems like its applying the first line of the above code, but skipping the last two lines.

Comment: This is because the `>` operator applies styles only to immediate children. If some of those styles were also to be applied to the sub table, you should keep them in the way you had done before (`.twocoltable th` etc), and use my suggestion only for styles which you don't want to apply to the sub table.

Comment: Interesting. I've changed my code a little bit to reflect the changes I mentioned, see above. Does anything look weird?

Comment: You still did not put the styles that you mean to share with sub tables on your original selectors. I'll update my answer hoping to clarify it a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Here's a jsfiddle with my original code, which shows the parent td borders being applied to the child table: https://jsfiddle.net/e529m76r/ If I edit it to include the &gt; signs between the elements (https://jsfiddle.net/f5r199pn/) then the border styles are lost in all the td elements.

Answer (score 1):

By using this notation: `.twocoltable tr`, you will apply that style to all children of `.twocoltable` that are `tr`, no matter how deep they are.

You can choose to get more specific by adding classes to your `tr` elements, etc. Or you can use the child selector, `>`. It ensures the style is only applied to immediate children: `.twocoltable > tr`.